# Getting a dom element before its displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently am trying to use a library that requires a dom element to be passed to it.
However I am dynamically creating a layout like this so the dom element doesnt exist at that time.
I wanted to know how i can pass the current dom element which will eventually be rendered ?

```
function addControl(domeElement)
{
 jsonTree.create(data, domeElement);
}

function () {
$(container).append(
    "<div class='myfancydiv'>" + addControl(this Div) + "</div>"
);
```

Comment: Call the function when you create the element.

Comment: what do i pass in as the domElement ?

Comment: I would imagine `jsontree` requires an element to be rendered before being able to be used.

Comment: `what do i pass in as the domElement ?` - the element you created

Comment: @zfrisch looks like it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `appendTo` so that you can easily retrieve the element after it is appended, then pass that element to your function:

```
let domElement = $("<div class='myfancydiv'></div>").appendTo(container)[0];

addControl(domElement);
```

**Note:** `[0]` is simply a way to grab the actual DOM element from the JQuery Object, instead of a reference to the JQuery Object itself.

---

Example:

```js
function demo(domEle) {
$(domEle).css({color: "blue"});
}

let el = $( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" )[0];
demo(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```